# Detect Unprintable ASCII Characters in String

Tags: vb.net

I'm using Visual Basic 2010 Express. I need to parse a string with unprintable characters in it. I need to detect ASCII 4 (End of Trans).

A scanner dumps data into a TextBox in my app.  In a loop, I am using:

```
If Chr(MyString.Chars(counter)) = 4 Then
   MsgBox("Found")
End If
```

This is not the correct syntax but should convey what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the scanner dumps the data into a textbox:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
   TextBox1.Text = "Some chars coming in from " & Chr(4) & " a scanner"
End Sub
```

[image]

Try something like this:

```
Dim MyString As String = TextBox1.Text

If MyString.Contains(Chr(4)) Then
   MessageBox.Show("Found")
End If
```

Or even something like this:

```
Dim MyString As String = TextBox1.Text
Dim counter As Integer = 26

If MyString.Chars(counter) = Chr(4) Then
   MessageBox.Show("Found")
End If
```

Comment: Brian, question.. VB seems to be stripping out the special characters from the textbox. Is there a way to maintain them so I can parse them?

Comment: I don't have this issue.  Perhaps something else is amiss?

Comment: Your example has the `chr` function in it, so I know the basic functionality works. However, when I change the string to my textbox, the scan data is devoid of the non-printable characters. I am 100% certain that the scanner is including the characters because I can see them in the proprietary scanner software that I am using. Would you know where I should look from here?

Comment: How does the data get from the scanner to the textbox?  Maybe something is happening during that process.

Comment: The data comes in through a USB port into the textbox that has focus. I even tried replacing the character with a human readable character but to no avail. I'm stumped.

Comment: If you don't see the special characters in the textbox, then it sounds like somewhere between the scanner and your app they are being stripped out.

Comment: Yeah, they are not there. But then again, these characters by nature are not visible by nature.

Comment: Yes, they are non-printable but at least for me, they show as a small square in the textbox.  So if you're not seeing that square, then I still suspect they are being stripped out somehow.

Comment: Wow, that's weird. I don't see those square characters at all in my textbox. And you don't think it's a property that needs to be set on the box? I'm not very familiar with VB in general. I'm not even sure what to search for.

Comment: I don't see a property to control whether special characters show or not.  Dropping a new textbox and changing no properties works like I show in my updated answer.

Comment: Sorry for so many questions, Brian, but what version of VB are you using? I'm on 2010 Express if that matters. Thanks for the screenshot, it's helpful.

Comment: I'm using VS2019, but I don't think that really matters.

Comment: Okay, Brian, thank you for being so helpful! I'll keep looking for a solution. I can use string position to find my values, but I'm sure you'd agree, that's really a terrible solution.